# Google App Engine Flexible Environment custom domain redirects to appspot-preview.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have setup a custom domain with a SSL certificate like it is indicated in [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en), but when I go to "mycustomdomain".com I get redirected to *.appspot-preview.com.

In that page there is a section called Before you begin indicating that:

> To use the latest App Engine Flexible release with a custom domain, please fill out **this form** to contact us.

But it [this form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/gae_flex_custom_domain) is not working

How can I stop this redirect?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent this redirect for the time being.  The reason for the application being redirected to `your-project-id.appspot-preview.com` is that the latest version of the App Engine Flexible environment (which uses `env: flex`) is on a different infrastructure.  This is temporary while much work is being done to promote the flexible environment to General Availability, at which point, this redirect should no longer happen.

The workaround **was** to use the [form you linked](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7296073?visit_id=1-636216881112027088-2505500874&rd=1) but that has since been turned down.  At present, there is no official process for having a custom domain whitelisted with one's `env: flex` application.   Nonetheless, we've received your request posted in this [related Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/4_2oVbRhMKY) and will do our best to reach out to you privately as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas. Do you have a rough timeframe for when promotion to general availability will be complete?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not.  As this is a significant effort affecting many components, customers and engineers alike, time frames for such changes can be very difficult to promise.  I also don't have the visibility that a product manager would.  Nonetheless, the best place to inquire about such an update is the [App Engine Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine).  We are fairly active there.  I encourage you to search and post there since as I'm certain this is an important issue to many eager developers and teams in the community.

Comment: This issue now appears to be resolved - the preview version of appspot is no longer used to display app results.